# Is there a book on differential geometry that doesn't mention the notion of charts?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, principal-bundles

What are some books/texts that use chart free coordinate free language for things otherwise written in a coordinate based formulation? I would like to learn about covariant differentiation, curvature, bundles, characteristic forms etc., but without any charts or local coordinates. 
The most important areas would be those with applications in physics like gauge theory or Hamiltonian mechanics, where I so often hear all mathematical literature uses coordinate free language, but I never seem to find any such text. They say that they are doing calculations using intrinsic methods; it makes you wonder where all the tedious coordinate manipulations went.

Milnor's monograph "Morse Theory for example is a horrible book written in a really bad prosaic style , baez's gauge fields knots and gravity and Mallios's modern differential geometry in gauge theories are the kind of material im interested in. 
Baez is awesome up untill the point he decides something is too abstract and breaks it down in a chosen basis..

Comment: This question is not fit for MathOverflow, but would find a very good home on Math.SE. Flagged it for migration.

Comment: Just for the record, FWIW, I personally think the question is just fine here on MathOverflow

Comment: Basic differential geometry can be phrased in a coordinate-free way but when you need to prove/check something you will find that coordinate computations are often shorter and easier, hence most (if not all) textbooks use both. You may like Chapters 1-2 of "Einstein manifolds" by Arthur L. Besse.

Comment: There is a book by Mallios called "Geometry of Vector Sheaves" (Vol. 2), where the author develops differential geometry via sheaf theory. There are two volumes, but the first volume is called differently IIRC. It deals with generalities on sheaves, sheaves of vector spaces, sheaf cohomology, multilinear algebra on sheaves etc., from what I understand. The second one is the geometric one and covers connections, curvature, characteristic classes and other things. I don't know if that would be useful to you.

Comment: @YemonChoi: I believe that you attribute to the OP intentions that he does not have. I interpret the question as asking for an exposition of differential geometry in the "new" style (i.e. without indices) as opposed to the "old" style (often used by physicists, involving lots of indices, be they abstract or concrete). If my interpretation is correct, then this is an undergraduate-level question. In particular, the OP should try to look at ["Foundations of Differential Geometry"](https://books.google.com/books?id=up-QDAEACAA) (by Kobayashi & Nomizu) and see if this is what he is looking for.

Comment: @YemonChoi: In particular, this question is *not* about differential geometry presented with sheaves, in a scheme-theoretic-like manner.

Comment: For Riemannian geometry (and therefore no gauge theory or Hamiltonian mechanics), Milnor's monograph "Morse Theory" has a famous coordinate-free exposition of the essentials of Riemannian geometry in one very short chapter. Cheeger and Ebin's book, "Comparison Theorems in Riemannian Geometry" also does everything without coordinates.

Comment: For $U(1)$ gauge theory (i.e., Maxwell's equations), see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72160/maxwells-equations-and-differential-forms

Comment: Dear @AlexM. My point had absolutely nothing to do with sheaves. It is more that I find myself needing "undergraduate level mathematics" (for certain values of undergraduate that really really really really are not as universal as some people seem to believe) in the course of actual research I am doing. It is also often the case that I don't immediately know the right words to be looking up or the right books to be reading, because if I did _I wouldn't be asking online_, I would be reading those books

Comment: @DeaneYang I think the information in your comments would make a perfectly reasonable answer, although it seems my opinion may be in a minority

Comment: I recall O'Neill's book *Semi-Riemannian Geometry with Applications to Relativity* generally exposits without coordinates.

Comment: Yemon, I'm happy to make it an answer, even if it's not well liked. Thanks.

Comment: I find this question strange:  a smooth manifold is by definition a (second-countable Hausdorff) topological space equipped with a collection of charts whose transition functions are smooth.  Presenting differential geometry without charts would require a fundamentally different definition for the basic object.

Comment: @July : yes that sounds like a step in the right direction, Modern Differential Geometry in Gauge Theories
Maxwell Fields, Volume I: Mallios, Anastasios is a great book but very hard which is not really a bad thing. I could find the volumes you mentioned free in pdf thaugh.

Comment: @macbeth: *a smooth manifold is by definition a (second-countable Hausdorff) topological space equipped with a collection of charts whose transition functions are smooth* That's one definition. Others are possible. Some are equivalent, some inequivalent. Differentiable manifolds are a subset of PL manifolds, which are a subset of topological manifolds. PL manifolds are defined in a way that's qualitatively different from your definition. Cf. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53021/defining-a-manifold-without-reference-to-the-reals and arxiv.org/abs/1405.0984 .

Comment: It might be helpful to get some clarification from the OP on whether what they want is really an exposition that's coordinate-free, or one that's index-free. These are different things. Abstract index notation is coordinate-free. IMO abstract index notation gives the best of both worlds. It's compact and expressive, while remaining coordinate-independent, and it can be easily translated to and from information expressed in a particular set of coordinates.

Comment: I am very surprised to read what the OP wrote about Milnor's book. It is widely regarded as one of the best books of geometry ever written. Robert MacPherson described it as "unimprovable". I understand it is a matter of taste, but please try to be diplomatic.

Comment: On further thought, in reaction to comments posted by Tyson, I think the idea of learning differential geometry in a coordinate-free framework from the start is misguided. My advice now is to learn everything from a good textbook, even if it uses coordinates or at least orthonormal bases of vector fields ("moving frames"). Once you understand it thoroughly from this point of view, making the transition to a coordinate-free framework is straightforward.

Comment: And I also agree with Ben's comment about Milnor's masterpiece.

Comment: Here's something to ponder.  In linear algebra you can tell whether a map is linear without reference to a basis.  In differential geometry, how do you tell whether a map is smooth without reference to charts?

Comment: I'll chime in with Deane, to say I am stunned, and in fact disgusted, by this pronouncement on Milnor's wonderful book (one of my favorites even though it is well outside the fields where I do research). I would strongly advise removing it.

Comment: 'tis a brave person indeed who pronounces anything written by Milnor as "horrible"!

Answer (score 15):

For Riemannian geometry (and therefore no gauge theory or Hamiltonian mechanics), I recall two beautiful coordinate-free expositions:

1)  Milnor's monograph "Morse Theory" has all of the essentials presented elegantly in one very short chapter.

2) Cheeger and Ebin's book, "Comparison Theorems in Riemannian Geometry" also does everything without coordinates.

For $U(1)$ gauge theory (i.e., Maxwell's equations), see

[Maxwell's equations and differential forms](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72160/maxwells-equations-and-differential-forms)

I would add that it was for me very difficult to learn well coordinate-free differential geometry without also grinding through a lot of messy calculations in coordinates. Learning coordinate-free differential geometry is like learning linear algebra using abstract vector spaces. As beautiful as that is, it is hard to appreciate without first learning linear algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I would add that although these books are co-ordinate-free in the sense that (mostly) the statements of main lemmas and propositions do not mention charts, the proofs of the lemmas and propositions often do involve charts.  Indeed, this is hard to avoid:  for example, how can you prove the existence of integral curves or geodesics without taking a chart and applying a theorem on the existence of solutions to systems of ODEs?

Comment: I would also add that almost any modern book on Riemannian geometry is co-ordinate-free in the same sense as these two books.  These two are the classics, perhaps, but there are more beginner-friendly books, Lee's for example, that take the same approach more slowly (because they're not racing to get to more advanced material).

Comment: Awesome, P.S. do you know any book on linear algebra using abstract vector spaces XD.when i was first learing about it something just felt wrong. Coordinate definitions and calculations simply dont do justice to otherwise very natural, elegant and really simple concepts and even calculations.

Comment: Lang's book, Linear Algebra, seems to do it abstractly. Almost any abstract algebra book will also do it that way. Books on functional analysis, too.

Comment: I have to agree with macbeth. I haven't looked closely at more modern books, but it's hard to imagine that they don't discuss the coordinate-free approach in detail. Besides Lee, I suggest looking at the book by Gallot, Hulin, and Lafontaine.

Comment: What is the exact title of that lee's book , its not riemann manifolds, thats far from coordinate free.Also by coordinate free linear algebra i mean for exapmle that it has intrinsic definitions of the trace and the determinant of linear functions. Such things are important cause they occur naturally in modern physics.

Comment: Both books deduce properties of the geodesic equation and the Jacobi equations from their description in local charts.

Comment: Igor, thanks for pointing that out. My memory failed me.

Comment: Eschenberg's notes on comparison geometry are beautifully written with plenty of coordinate free calculations. As a side note, by using comparison theory for the Riccati equation, the exposition is greatly simplified compared with Cheeger and Ebin. See in particular the Topogonov triangle theorem.

Comment: Andrews and Hopper has a very nice presentation (for a reader already familiar with DG) and mixture of both coordinate and coordinate free language.

Comment: Although the comments—including one from you!—made clear it is very much a minority view ([1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283938/#comment701221_283938) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283938/#comment701232_283938) [3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283938/#comment701241_283938) [4](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283938/#comment701251_283938)), it may be worth noting that your first recommendation, Milnor's book, was explicitly excluded by @Tyson.